# Loading GeoJSON into map using JavaScript API in ESRI

Tags: javascript, geojson, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm new to ESRI Map.  I'm working on latest version of JavaScript API.

I'm trying to load GeoJSON from [this link](https://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json) into my Map.  I'm able to load GeoJSON from ESRI Feature Service URL.

I wanted to load GeoJSON from an object.  My code goes like this.

```
require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/widgets/Legend",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
      Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, Legend
    ) {

      var defaultSym = {
        type: "simple-fill", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
        outline: { // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
          color: "lightgray",
          width: 0.5
        }
      };

      var renderer = {
        type: "simple", // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
        symbol: defaultSym
      };

      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "streets"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-85.050200, 33.125524],
        zoom: 4
      });

      var usOutline = ...... A single feature from the feature collection in link.
      var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        source: usOutline.geometry,
        title: 'Hello',
        geometryType: "Polygon",
        renderer: renderer
      });

      map.add(featureLayer);


    });
```

How can I load the GeoJSON?

Answer (score 4):

Check out this code snippet/post:

[Importing GeoJSON data in ArcGIS Javascript maps](http://www.geothread.net/importing-geojson-data-in-arcgis-javascript-maps/)

```
function requestData() {
  var requestHandle = esriRequest({
    url: "data/sample.json",
    callbackParamName: "jsoncallback"
  });
  requestHandle.then(requestSucceeded, requestFailed);
}

function requestSucceeded(response, io) {
  //loop through the items and add to the feature layer
  var features = [];
  array.forEach(response.features, function(item) {
    var attr = {};
    //pull in any additional attributes if required
    attr["some_other_field"] = item.properties.<some_chosen_field>;

    var geometry = new Point(item.geometry.coordinates[0], item.geometry.coordinates[1]);

    var graphic = new Graphic(geometry);
    graphic.setAttributes(attr);
    features.push(graphic);
  });

  featureLayer.applyEdits(features, null, null);
}

function requestFailed(error) {
  console.log('failed');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort.  Unable to plot geojson with this code.  This plot's points from the each co-ordinates in geojson.  Moreover this doesn't support version 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

Use GeoJSONLayer for this task:

Ex:

```
  var stuffLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
        url: "https://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json"
  });

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets",
    layers: [stuffLayer]
  });
```

Read more here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-geojson/index.html